# How do I stop Visual Studio 2022 find starting a new set of editor tabs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I use various finds to do basically all my navigation in VS... haven't been back to .NET for a while, and are using VS 2022, but there's a behaviour I can't handle, and I'm wondering how to stop it.

Basically

- I have a set of code open in a bunch of tabs.
- I hit the key to open the "find in files" window and put in a search
- It opens a new pane with find results in it.
- Clicking on any file inside the find results opens that file IN THIS NEW PANE

So suddenly I have two sets of editor tabs. I never want two sets of editor tabs.

How do I stop it doing this?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what the IDE looks like after clicking on the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Find Results window is Docked as Tabbed Document. In this case, right click the Find Results tab and select Dock to fix the problem.